# How to issue http request with golang context capability but not by golang http client?

Tags: go

I found golang context is useful for canceling the processing of the server during a client-server request scope.

I can use `http.Request.WithContext` method to issue the http request with context, but if the client side is NOT using golang, is it possible to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but using a context for sometime like a timeout is possible for both handling incoming requests and outbound requests.

For incoming requests you can use the context and send back a timeout http status code indicating that the server want able to process the request. It doesn't matter what the client sends you, you get to decide the timeout on your own with the server.

For outgoing requests you don't need the server to even know you have a timeout. You simply set a timeout and have your request just cancel if it doesn't get a response back in a set time. This means you likely won't get any response from the server because your code would cancel the outgoing request.

Now are you asking for an example of how to code on of these? Or just if both are possible?